# Android: Using WiFi over LAN

Tags: android, wifi, lan

For debugging purposes I set the IP address on my phone to 192.168.178.220 and this connects to my PC over a wireless router to access a web app I have running in IIS on my PC. The web app uses 192.168.178.201. I have to use the desktop app DnsSpeeder to act as my DNS server in order for my phone app to communicate with the web app using its domain name instead of its IP address. I need to do this because I use a subdomain that shares the same IP address with other web apps.

Normally this works but if I leave my phone untouched for a minute or so, the phone cannot resolve the domain name. I even tried a third party tool and just entered the IP address and it cannot connect to the web app. But after a few minutes the connection works fine with either just the IP address or domain name. If I use the third party tool to ping a site that is on the Internet, like google.com, there also appears to be a long delay.

My Internet connection appears to always be on and under my settings I have it set to never go off, so I can't see how it could be the WiFi radio itself.

Could the problem be with using a LAN IP address or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting!  Sure sounds like something is going to sleep on the phone.  Have you run a packet sniffer such as Wireshark on your PC to determine if the expected DNS requests are making it from the phone to DnsSpeeder?

Comment: Great idea. Forgot about Wireshark. Turned out to be a second device on the LAN had the same IP address. Changed the IP address of the second device and everything now works fine. Thanks a million!